# Static css and js loads when using STATICFILES_DIRS not STATIC_URL

Tags: python, html, django, pycharm

My settings.py is

```
STATIC_URL = '/some_location/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [ multiple path ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My base .html with the directory structure is,

[image]

My directory root from image above

```
-project directory
-->appname
-->static
---->css
------>master.css
---->js
----->master.js
```

I use pycharm IDE.

```
The error message I get is 

"GET /some_location/static/js/master.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1736
"GET /some_location/static/css/master.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1742
```

When I use the above location `/some_location/static/js/master.js` in the browser I get to see the file content.

What I do to correctly load the `.css` and `.js` on the development server in Pycharm?

**Update 1:**

This seems to have worked, but not sure why. Can someone clarify why one works but not the other

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's hopefully some clarification:

- `STATIC_URL` tells Django which url it should prepend for all links to static files when rendering `{% static %}` links. For development, it's easiest to set it to `/static/`. On your production settings, it would probably point to a cloud provider url behind a CDN (e.g `https://my-cdn.cloudflare.net/static/`).
- `STATIC_ROOT` tells the `collectstatic` management command where to copy all the static files of your project. This is usually not relevant on your development machine (you serve the static files directly from your project) but is relevant for deploying in production: you'll want to copy all your static files to a location **outside** of your project directory (e.g. a cloud storage bucket like S3 of Amazon).
- Your static files should be located **inside** a `static` directory inside each of your apps (ie. in your case the `appname/static` directory). If you also have a separate directory, like `static` directly in your project BASE_DIR, then you tell Django that using `STATICFILES_DIRS`. This tells `runserver` to also look there. On production, it tells `collectstatic` where to gather all static files from.

So to summarise: `STATIC_URL/path_to/my_file` is the URL a user sees in the browser, when using the built-in Django runserver, `STATIC_URL` is stripped and `path_to/my_file` is searched in all the app static directories and directory listed in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

I've also written a [blog post](https://www.dedi.co/blog/entries/2018/12/17/deploying-static-files-aws-django-part-1) about this.

Comment: thanks for clarifying the different setting workings in production ad in development